# Sphero Android Joystick View

Tags: java, android, sphero-api, sphero

How can I use JoystickView in Sphero-Android application? I followed [this](https://github.com/orbotix/Sphero-Android-SDK/tree/master/samples/UISample#joystick-view) link in order to implement Joystick View into my layout, but there is no package named **com.orbotix.spherocam.ui.joystick.JoystickView**  in RobotLibrary.jar, so it is pointless to add this view into my layout file like the way it's shown in the tutorial. (and when I run the application, it crashes with the following exception)

```
06-01 12:23:06.071: E/AndroidRuntime(22204): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.orbotix.spherocam.ui.joystick.JoystickView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.ecem.whereissphero-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.ecem.whereissphero-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
06-01 12:23:06.071: E/AndroidRuntime(22204):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:53)
06-01 12:23:06.071: E/AndroidRuntime(22204):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
06-01 12:23:06.071: E/AndroidRuntime(22204):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
06-01 12:23:06.071: E/AndroidRuntime(22204):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:559)
06-01 12:23:06.071: E/AndroidRuntime(22204):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
06-01 12:23:06.071: E/AndroidRuntime(22204):    ... 21 more
```

How can I implement this? Please help me on this one.

Answer (score 1):

it's orbotix.robot.widgets.joystick.JoystickView;

Comment: It still doesn't work since there is no package named "orbotix.robot.widgets.joystick.JoystickView" :(

Comment: You need to download the UIsample .
JoystickView is a controller they build in the sample, and not part of the SDK